# Dataset: Annual trade between countries

Tags: international-trade, data-request

Where can I find data about the annual trade between countries?
Say for example the annual exports from Pakistan to China and annual exports from China to Pakistan.

Is WTO or UN or other international institution (IMF, WB etc) hosting such data?

I can find on [this site](https://www.statista.com/statistics/525352/china-export-of-goods-to-vietnam/) some data but not for all countries

Answer (score 1):

There is no site with every single country because in some cases data are not available but world trade organization (WTO) has free dataset with basic trade statistics for large number of countries (see [here](https://wits.worldbank.org/countrystats.aspx?lang=en)).

Answer (score 1):

The best source for these data is UN Comtrade. You can download bilateral trade flows for a large number of countries using the API here. https://comtrade.un.org/data/doc/api

You won't be able to get all countries because some countries use different systems to classify trade or have governments that do not collect reliable data.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I've found these two sites:

https://wits.worldbank.org/CountrySnapshot/en/PAK/textview

https://oec.world/en/profile/bilateral-country/chn/partner/pak